# Setting time limited temporary password for user in azure active directory using graph api

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

We have a requirement where we are creating users in azure active directory with a temporary password. Requirement is such that we need to give the user a temporary password with expiry time limited to 1 Hr. In case user doesn't login within an hour, password need to reissued using a workflow.

Question is,

> Is there a way to create temporary password for an user in AAD with
>   expiry time as low as 1 Hr? I am aware expiry of password can be set
>   at active directory level which can be limited to minimum 14 Days.

I would really appreciate any help on this.